# Busqueda independientes por columnas Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Soy nuevo en la plataforma y en SQL
Estoy intentado crear un stored procedure que agregue 2 columnas con valores de columnas existentes y despues consultar en el stored procedure con parametros de fecha ,mi tabla se llama Balanza
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que la consulta de el stored procedure Agregara una columna nueva llamada Monto2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregar una columna Fecha2 igual con valores existentes de Fecha

y a su vez que Fecha solo busque valores en Monto y Fecha2 Busque valores en Monto2

Espero ser claro con el problema

Gracias de antemano

```
select Clasificación,Monto as Monto ,Monto as Monto2 from Balanzas where Fecha = 'feb-18' and Fecha = 'ene-18'
```

Mi resultado esperado es :[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola creo que la solucion mas sencilla a tu caso es trasladar el resultado de tu query a una subquery y desde alli hacer la consulta por las columnas creadas,

```
SELECT * 
FROM    ( 
         SELECT Clasificación,Monto AS Monto ,Monto AS Monto2, Fecha AS Fecha, Fecha AS Fecha2 FROM Balanzas 
        ) AS tabla 
WHERE Fecha = @fecha1 and Fecha2 = @fecha2
```

Sin embargo tengo muchas dudas de porque querías duplicar una columna completa, siento que esta parte debe ser revisada y probablemente llegues a una mejor solución.

UPDATE:

Si tu intención es traer el registro cuando coincide con cualquiera de las fechas por parámetros deberías hacer lo siguiente.

```
WHERE fecha IN (@fecha1, @fecha2)
```

Comment: Hola  ,el motivo de la columna completa es porque Monto 2 debe de coincidir con la busqueda de Fecha2, pero aun asi no me trae datos

Comment: ya que la columna fecha y fecha2 son exactas.. podrías comparar ambos parámetros fecha y fecha2 versus la columna fecha.

Comment: Eso como se podría implementar :(

Comment: seria algo así 
WHERE fecha = parametrofecha1 AND fecha = parametrofecha2

lo que no tiene mucha lógica ya que solo traería resultados donde los parámetros son iguales.

Si tu intención es traer el registro cuando coincide con cualquiera de las fechas por parámetros deberías hacer lo siguiente.

WHERE fecha IN (parametroFecha1, parametroFecha2)

Comment: Genial! Es lo que estaba buscando

Comment: edito la respuesta para que no se pierda en los mentarios.